# Need a example to use dll in vs

Tags: dll, cmake

I faced a problem when i migrated a project from Linux to windows for the visual studio seem can not use dll lib directly. I look through a number of materials  and known i seem should use IMPORTED in add_library(...), but i can not find a practical example about how to use it and i used it like this:

```
add_library(hello_lib SHARED hello.c)
add_library(hello_lib SHARED IMPORTED)
```

And a ERROR happened

```
CMake Error at sub_haha/CMakeLists.txt:6 (add_library):
add_library cannot create imported target "haha_lib" because another target
with the same name already exists.
```

Could you please give me one or some? BTW the dll lib seem could be used in Mingw makefile on windows.

Comment: As error message tells, you cannot create two targets with same name. Choose another name for imported library.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I know this error, i just do not know how to use it to link dll in windows.

Comment: For link with library `target_link_libraries` command should used, as usual. Do not understand your problem.

Comment: For some details on creating/using shared libraries in CMake see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062728/cmake-link-shared-library-on-windows) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941443/cmake-linking-against-shared-library-on-windows-error-about-not-finding-lib-fi).